# WP7 and Http-Referer

Tags: windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest, referer

I've written an app that shows comments from Disqus and when I run it as a .NET application on my desktop it works great. It sends a http requst and then deserialize the json objects. But when I move the code to my Windows Phone app I get an error from Disqus.

It appears that because Windows Phone decides to add a random http referer my request fails. I'm not allowed to change the referer on the windows phone I get the message *"The 'Referer' header cannot be modified directly."* if I try to do that.

Is there a workaround for this that doesn't require me to build a proxy that removes the referer header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can gather from [this post](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/63150/456583.aspx#456583), there's no way to remove the `Referer header` without using a proxy service. Apparently this code worked for one person:

```
var uri = new Uri ("http://some.where");
var request = WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp.Create (uri) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Headers ["user-agent"] = "My user agent string";
request.BeginGetResponse (...);
```

However, it seems that the general consensus in that thread is that there's no way to change it, but it should be fixed in the `Mango` version.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `request.Referer = referer` use `request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Referer] = referer` and it will work